# не работает img с cover только в HTML

Tags: html, css, img

Не хочу чтобы url вклепить в css, именно в HTML, потому что подготовить с AngularJS . 
 Покажу изображение GIF https://i.gyazo.com/200d02b47695f87dd87f2dfff656814d.gif

```
<img src="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/5772b3c08130511f7703bafb/57dffb10ee0df0d90eb761ab_trump-clinton.jpg" class="thumbnail-small" alt="">

.thumbnail-small {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 overflow: auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите постоянную высоту.

Если вам нужно ограничение по высоте - ставьте `max-height`